# Netsuite No Web Services Permission

Tags: netsuite

I'm currently fighting with Netsuite's API and for the past while was getting somewhere, until quite randomly my user was no longer able to log in at all (WebFault: Server raised fault: 'You do not have permission to access web services feature.').  Is there a hidden max API calls/hour that I've hit?  I've gone through and checked all 3 relevant places for web services (Company, role, and user is in role).  Can anyone shed some light on this (quite frankly nightmare of an) api?

```
DEBUG:suds.client:sending to (https://webservices.netsuite.com/services/NetSuitePort_2014_1)
message:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="urn:core_2014_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns2="urn:messages_2014_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns1:Body>
      <ns2:login>
         <ns2:passport>
            <ns0:email>*********</ns0:email>
            <ns0:password>*******</ns0:password>
            <ns0:account>********</ns0:account>
            <ns0:role>******</ns0:role>
         </ns2:passport>
      </ns2:login>
   </ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
DEBUG:suds.client:headers = {'SOAPAction': u'"login"', 'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'}
ERROR:suds.client:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="urn:core_2014_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns2="urn:messages_2014_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns1:Body>
      <ns2:login>
         <ns2:passport>
            <ns0:email>***************</ns0:email>
            <ns0:password>*********</ns0:password>
            <ns0:account>********</ns0:account>
            <ns0:role>*********</ns0:role>
         </ns2:passport>
      </ns2:login>
   </ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
DEBUG:suds.client:http failed:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode><faultstring>You do not have permission to access web services feature.</faultstring><detail><platformFaults:insufficientPermissionFault xmlns:platformFaults="urn:faults_2014_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"><platformFaults:code>WS_PERMISSION_REQD</platformFaults:code><platformFaults:message>You do not have permission to access web services feature.</platformFaults:message></platformFaults:insufficientPermissionFault><ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">partners-java026.svale.netledger.com</ns1:hostname></detail></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

I was successfully logging in and out, as well as accessing the getServerTime() method when it blew up on me, and I haven't been able to log in since.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One thing to look at is that any change in permissions on UI doesn't impact web services immediately. It takes about 30 minutes to propagate new permissions in Webservices.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, but I don't think that's the issue here sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Check-list:
Under Roles

1) Web Services Only Role checked

2) Check that they have the web services permission

Employee

1) check that they have the role and the password is correct

2) Concurrent Web Services User is checked

Answer (score 0):

RE: You Max Calls per Hour Question.

No that is not the case. A Normal Netsuite User is allowed to process 1 API request at any one time, if a second is submitted while the first is still processing it will be rejected with an exception.

You can upgrade your user to a 'Suite Plus' License to achieve 10 concurrent requests for many £££££

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the user's Role.  Go to the Permissions>Setup and make sure Web Services is listed.  If not, add it and save.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Consider elaborating your answer a little bit.